# Can an object dynamically loaded with possible exceptions be declared as final?

Tags: java, variables, dynamic, exception, final

At first I was going to make the question solely about the `Image` class, but I wanted to make it as broadly applicable as possible.

Basically, here's the scenario.  I'm making a file for GUI constants, and in this file I'd like to have final variables for each of the `Image`s I'm using.  So my fields are declared like this `UP_ARROW` is:

```
public static final Image UP_ARROW;
```

Then I try to load them when the `ImageIO` API, like so:

```
static {
    UP_ARROW = ImageIO.read(new File("img/upArrow.png"));
}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't valid, compilable code, because it explicitly `throws IOException`, which I have to deal with.  So I modify it and surround it with a try/catch:

```
static {
    try {
        UP_ARROW = ImageIO.read(new File("img/upArrow.png"));
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Now I get a different compiler error.  This time it says there's a possibility that the field may not have been initialized.  Okay, that makes sense.  Thank you for pointing that out to me, compiler.  That seems like an easy fix:

```
static {
    try {
        UP_ARROW = ImageIO.read(new File("img/upArrow.png"));
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        UP_ARROW = null;
    }
}
```

Now, no matter what, the `UP_ARROW` must be populated with either my image or `null`.  I'm prepared to declare victory and move on.  But now I get *another*, unexpected compiler error:

[image: The final field UP_ARROW may already have been assigned]

... Foiled again, compiler!

Hence the question: is there any way to get around this, such that I can dynamically load final fields at runtime?  Or do I declare defeat and simply make the `Image`s non-final?

Also, an explanation as to why the compiler won't allow this would be helpful as well.  As I understand it, based on the code above, the `UP_ARROW` object *could not* have been assigned before reaching the `catch{}` block, *because that's what must have thrown the exception*.  So if the `try{}` executes successfully, only one assignment takes place.  If it does not execute successfully, still only one assignment take place.  How is that not valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
static {
    Image up_arrow = null;
    try {
        up_arrow = ImageIO.read(new File("img/upArrow.png"));
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        // log the error?
    }
    UP_ARROW = up_arrow;
}
```

It might make sense to enclose the final assignment in a `finally` block .

Answer (score 1):

NPE's answer is good, but I think this one is (based off his and) better:

```
public enum Arrows {
    UP ("img/upArrow.png"),
    DOWN ("img/downArrow.png"),
    LEFT ("img/leftArrow.png"),
    RIGHT ("img/rightArrow.png");

    public final Image myImage;

    private Arrows(String fileName) {
        Image tempImage;
        try {
            tempImage = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            tempImage = null;
        }
        myImage = tempImage;
    }
}
```

This solves your problem and gives you all the advantages of an `enum` over `static final` variables.